# NUnit async task fails "Method has non-void return value, but no result is expected"

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, resharper, nunit-3.0

I'm running unit tests in ReSharper with NUnit 3.10.

I'm getting this error when doing a simple async test:

> Method has non-void return value, but no result is expected

My test is literally:

```
[Test]
public async Task Nothing()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

It says in the [documentation](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/test.html) that this is in fact the correct way to run async tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the issues was that instead of using a NuGet package, the references were to a DLL that's compiled targeting .NET Framework 3.5. Using a NuGet package of NUnit fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

For those working in Unity, make sure you are using the updated Test Framework Package, at least `2.0.1`. It is currently in pre-release so you will need to enable `show pre-release` in the Package Manager.

[Documentation here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.test-framework@2.0/manual/reference-async-tests.html) for more about the feature.

Answer (score 0):

For any Unity user that comes across this: I had the issue that I was using `TestCaseSource` on a `UnityTest`, which caused the above error message. Instead it is recommended to use `ValueSource`: [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.test-framework@1.1/manual/reference-tests-parameterized.html).